# Trouble making struct for JSON coinbase API historical data

Tags: json, go

How should I build out my struct for historical bitcoin data if my dates will constantly change?  I am using https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ to build the struct that I intend to use when I hit this end point https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?start=2013-09-01&end=2013-09-05 .  Please note that there is a start and end date that can vary.

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Bpi struct {
        Two0130901 float64 `json:"2013-09-01"`
        Two0130902 float64 `json:"2013-09-02"`
        Two0130903 float64 `json:"2013-09-03"`
        Two0130904 float64 `json:"2013-09-04"`
            Two0130905 float64 `json:"2013-09-05"`
    } `json:"bpi"`
    Disclaimer string `json:"disclaimer"`
    Time       struct {
            Updated    string    `json:"updated"`
        UpdatedISO time.Time `json:"updatedISO"`
    } `json:"time"`
}
```

I would like to get to a place where it has Date and Price.  For example

```
{"2013-09-01":128.2597,
 "2013-09-02":127.3648,
 "2013-09-03":127.5915,
 "2013-09-04":120.5738,
 "2013-09-05":120.5333}
```

With the intention that I could be requesting for any date range, not just those five days.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the Bpi struct, use a map:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Bpi map[string]float64 `json:"bpi"`
    Disclaimer string `json:"disclaimer"`
    Time       struct {
            Updated    string    `json:"updated"`
        UpdatedISO time.Time `json:"updatedISO"`
    } `json:"time"`
}
```

This should give you exactly what you want.